# How can I write a nested IF statement in Zapier?

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to use Numbers: Spreadsheet style formula to write a nested IF statement and I keep getting this error: Error parsing response. We got: " Show details. Here is the statement:

`If("{{Alpine School District Schools}}"<>"", "{{Alpine School District Schools}}", If ("{{Bonsall Unified School District Schools}}"<>"","{{Bonsall Unified School District Schools}}", "NA")`

(As an FYI, when I copy and pasted this here I removed the numbers that preceded the fields when copying and pasting `{{110470936__Alpine School District Schools}}`)

This is stating if the field (which is a picklist) Alpine School District is not blank, add the school selected in this field; if it is blank but Bonsall School district is not blank, add the school selected in the Bonsall School District field, if Bonsall is also blank, add “NA”.

Any guidance on how to write to correctly is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have enough closing parens on the end of your statement. Here's your input, but spaced out to be more informative:

```
If(
  "{{Alpine School District Schools}}"<>"", 
  "{{Alpine School District Schools}}", 
  If (
    "{{Bonsall Unified School District Schools}}"<>"",
    "{{Bonsall Unified School District Schools}}", 
    "NA"
  )
  <-- missing paren
```

Fixing it may be as easy as adding `)` to the end of your statement.